# AttributeError , 'super' object has no attribute 'save', in class based view

Tags: python, django

I am new the Django and I am unable to save the Registration form using the Class Based View. I have made the Abstract user in the Models as shown below.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login 
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user non superuser
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser 
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_type   = models.CharField(max_length= 120, choices=u_type)
    # confirm     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # confirmed_date     = models.DateTimeField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #username
    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #['full_name'] #python manage.py createsuperuser

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

I have used Form for creating the Registration form as shown below
forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
password1 = forms.CharField(label='password')
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password')
user_email = forms.CharField(label='Email')
full_name = forms.CharField(label='Full Name')


class Meta:
    model = User 
    fields = ('full_name', 'email','user_type')


def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('password does not match')
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user_mail = self.cleaned_data.get('user_email')
    print(user_mail)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    if(commit):
        user.save()

    return user
```

this is the view file for the form

views.py

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url='/login'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        request = self.request
        # f = JobForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print(form)
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
        return redirect('/')
```

The issue I am facing is when I am trying to save the registration form then it is giving me the error 'super' object has no attribute 'save'. Currently I am struggling to save the form using the Class Based View.

Comment: You are showing the code for `RegisterForm`, but seem to use `RegistrationForm` in your view. Is this correct or a typo?

Comment: can you show all error? may be you import forms from wrong place, not from django(from django import forms)

Comment: Also (unrelated but...) you're not using `FormView.form_valid` correctly - when this method is called, the form has already been populated and validated.

Comment: yes there was a mistake while posting the question, I was using normal form instead of ModelForm. After correcting that, now I am not facing the above mentioned error but form is not getting saved.

Comment: Is the form not getting saved or the User object? Because you're passing commit=False and have an if statement not to save the User when commit=False.

I'd recommend reading up on ModelForms, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform because the code above applies to a regular form.

Comment: @JosvanLeeuwen  Thank you for the help, It is working now